# Is it possible to draw an X inside of a Box w/o breaking these rules?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

The task I have been given is to draw an X in a box with 4 rules in play

Rule 1: you can’t lift your pen off the paper
Rule 2: you can’t overlap, or draw through lines
Rule 3: you can’t draw anything outside of the box
Rule 4: you can’t fold the paper you’re writing on.

I’m starting to feel that it’s **impossible**

Comment: Regarding 4: only "fold", not "curl" or "tear"?

Comment: @Eric Towers I think neither of fold, curl or tear. I also agree with OP that it seems impossible

Comment: Can you draw on the box? If not, this is impossible, since a way to do this would imply the existence of a hamiltonian circuit on the "X" graph, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Does the _outline_ of an X count?

Comment: Are you asked to draw a X inside a previously provided box or are you asked to draw both an X and its enclosing box, subject to the four rules?

Answer (score 0):

Draw a diamond.
/\
\/
Start from the top of / in \/ and move downward.

Tear the paper horizontally in half at the widest part of the diamond.
/\
~
\/

Move the top half to below the bottom half.
\/
/\

Through all of this keep your pen at the bottom of \ in /\.
Now you can continue drawing to make a surrounding box.